# How to get next row in SQL server 2008 unsorted table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
Shift | Eqmt | StartTime | Category | Event
1201    A201   0           2          1
1204    A201   235         3          0
1202    A202   5413        5          1
1205    A203   213         6          1
1206    A204   4313        1          0
```

I want to add **all the next row** GIVEN ONE, but there is one consideration, the table first must be sorted by Eqmt,Shift and StartTime (in that order, all desc)

Final result must look like this:

```
Shift | Eqmt | StartTime | Category | Event | ShiftF | EqmtF | StartTimeF | CategoryF | EventF
1201    A201   0           2          1       1201     A201    235          3          0
1201    A201   235         3          0       1202     A201    0            2          1
1202    A201   0           2          1       1201     A202    213          6          1
1201    A202   213         6          1       1202     A202    4313         1          0
1202    A202   4313        1          0       1203     A202    0            2          1
```

In MS SQL 2012 we have new window functions like FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE, unfortunately in sql 2008 these functions are missing.

Comment: I don't understand how you get from your sample table to your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a simple self join to me:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT Shift, Eqmt, StartTime, Category, Event,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Eqmt DESC, Shift DESC, StartTime DESC) As Rn
    FROM TableName
)

SELECT t0.Shift, t0.Eqmt, t0.StartTime, t0.Category, t0.Event,
       t1.Shift, t1.Eqmt, t1.StartTime, t1.Category, t1.Event
FROM cte t0
JOIN cte t1
    ON t0.Rn + 1 = t1.Rn
```

Comment: Thanks!, My knowledge in SQL is not enough to work with consecutive rows, from this I can finish my desired query